# Parameterized value taking string value in typescript key value object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an object in typescript that has a string key and a string value.

```
const titleValue: string = "key";

const objectINeed = {
    titleValue: 'value'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(objectINeed))
```

This prints

```
"{"titleValue":"value"}"
```

I instead want this to return {"key" : "value"}

[TS Play link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCWUA2BTAagQyQVxQLhmgCd4wBzGAXhgCIA3LXGgbgChXRJYQAjAKxTAoASQByKFABMqMAN6sYiuIlSYc+GAHJJKAGYZsSWA3UwAjJtYBfNh3AQQqAHRIQZABQApAMoB5UU7EpGTwugCe7rwCQmISkgCU8UA)

I am not able to understand why the `titleValue` variable's stored value is not being picked up. Apologies if the title of the question is making it difficult to understand. I did not have better words for my problem as I am quite new to typescript and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `titleValue` in `[]` parantheses, so it uses the value of `titleValue` as key instead of the word titleValue:

```js
const titleValue: string = "key";

const objectINeed = {
    [titleValue]: 'value'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(objectINeed))
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does it happen like this though - treat an existing variable like a string. This is quite confusing.

Comment: You assumption that this syntax should treat the property name as a variable is simply wrong. This works like this in some other languages, but not in javascript. You can read more on object initializers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer especially the part about: "Computed property names".